# Observable not updating the view

Tags: angular, rxjs, async-pipe

I'm trying to build a [scheduler component](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/fullcalendar/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/src/lib/components/fullcalendar) for angular. However, when creating events it seems that the view is not being updated.

[image: Angular schedular component]

I've created a [minimal StackBlitz that demonstrates the issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tvaddv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

### EDIT

I created a [StackBlitz with the calendar component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wmax1h?file=src/app/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.component.html) too. Note that the labels are being updated, but the divs on the calendar aren't.

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.calendarEvents$ = new BehaviorSubject<CalendarEvent[]>([]);

    this.calendarEventParts$ = this.calendarEvents$
      .pipe(map((events) => {
        // Split event over the days it goes...
        return events.map(ev => <CalendarEventPart>{
          calendarEvent: ev
        });
      }));
  }

  calendarEvents$: BehaviorSubject<CalendarEvent[]>;
  calendarEventParts$: Observable<CalendarEventPart[]>;

  onAddEvent() {
    this.christmas = {...};
    this.calendarEvents$.pipe(take(1))
      .pipe(map((events) => events.push(this.christmas)))
      .subscribe(() => {});
  }

  onChangeChristmasStart() {
    this.christmas.start = new Date(2022, 11, 24);
  }
}
```

The `BehaviorSubject` updates the view as expected, but after using the `map` operator the view isn't being updated. I've already done `this.calendarEvents$.next(data)` but this does not solve the core issue, and prevents from property changes being detected.

### Edit

[I've updated the code in order to look for changes manually](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/commit/9e5164c5508b58563fac6a8780e0faaba42e525d) and force trigger the change detector explicitly. However even when calling `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` only when necessary, the view is still not updated.

Comment: Please include the code of your HTML

Comment: It's inside the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tvaddv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) and would stuff the question too much

Comment: Not sure what you want for the parts, but hopefully this will give you some hints? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5lvjk3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks. `this.events$.next([...this.events$.value, this.newEvent]);` did the trick for me. But now I'm still facing an issue that not all of the view is being updated. [Here's the code of the calendar component](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/fullcalendar/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/src/lib/components/fullcalendar/components/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.component.ts). I'll add a gif with the demo too.

Comment: I added a gif to the question, which includes your suggestions. I can see the data changing in the `| json` evaluations, but the divs on the component aren't appearing until I create a new event (which in fact updates the `BehaviorSubject`). How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your `calendarEvents$` behaviour subject.

```
onAddEvent() {
   this.christmas = {...};
   this.calendarEvents$.next([...this.calendarEvents$.value, this.christmas]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This fixes part of the problem. But I still have issues with the divs not being rendered while dragging. However, i can clearly see the labels updating. Only after a new Event is being pushed to the `Observable<[]>`, the events are appearing on the calendar. I've added a gif to the question.

Comment: [I've done the same thing](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/fullcalendar/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/src/lib/components/fullcalendar/components/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.component.ts#L195) when the `event.end` changes, and it works fine now. However, I still don't understand why the divs aren't being updated properly, whilst the labels are. But anyway, it works like a charm now.